# Forever remembered

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

0

I need the correct way to say "Always remembered" for a deceased male to go on an album. Semper memoriam Is what I've found. Please correct or confirm Thank you all

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is the phrase meant to be something only one person is wishing to do, or is this a sentiment that is meant to be from multiple people?

Answer (score 1):

"semper commonētur" would be the direct translation of "(he is) always remembered"; yet alternatively "semper in memoria nostra" as to say "always in our mind", would also convey the same meaning.

Comment: Isn't *reminisci* a deponent?

Comment: Shoot! Yes - how about commonētur instead?